# How to change the height of a section in small devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap for making my website and I want to change the height of my section on smaller devices so I added this code to my css file:

```
@media(max-width: 768px){
.services{
    height:2000px;
}
}
.services{
    height:1000px;
    background-blend-mode: darken;
    background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), url('../img/bg-2.jpg');
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

But it does not working and again it shows the normal height of 1000px on small devices! So how to do this ?

Comment: Add `@media` definition after the normal one -> https://jsfiddle.net/pL2hgdtm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the second declaration (1000px) overwrites the first one (2000px). See attached screenshot from the Chrome Developer Tools.

[image]

Solution: Just switch the order of the declarations (see snippet below).

```css
.services{
    height:1000px;
    background-blend-mode: darken;
    background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), url('../img/bg-2.jpg');
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
.services{
    height:2000px;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="services">
Foo
</div>
```

Comment: While you could also use `!important`, this is the better practice!